# What would be the C# equivalent of <T extends Comparable> implements Comparable<Transition <T>>?

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to convert some Java code into C# code. What would be the C# equivalent of the following Java code?

```
public class Transition<T extends Comparable> implements Comparable<Transition<T>>{}
```

I tried replacing the words `extends` and `implements` by a `:`, but it doesn't compile...

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for constraints in generic type:

```
public class Transition<T> : IComparable<Transition<T>> where T : IComparable
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This gives me: error CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected

Comment: Thank you for your help!